# Как проверить если ли в объекте ключ с определённым значением?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как узнать есть ли в объекте любое значение со статусом 1 ?

То есть нужно просто условие `if (obj) { } else { }`

```js
let obj = {
  a: {
    datetime: 1619808076,
    status: 1
  },
  b: {
    datetime: 1619808077,
    status: 0
  },
  c: {
    datetime: 1619808078,
    status: 0
  },
};

console.log(obj);
```

Можно на `js` или `jquery`

Comment: Перебираешь все ключи и проверяешь статус

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если заранее известны структура объекта и уровень вложенности значения, можно так:

```js
let obj = {
  a: {
    datetime: 1619808076,
    status: 1
  },
  b: {
    datetime: 1619808077,
    status: 0
  },
  c: {
    datetime: 1619808078,
    status: 0
  },
};

if (Object.values(obj).some(entry => entry.status === 1)) {
  console.log('Found.');
} else {
  console.log('Not found.');
}
```